# Trying to use Slider to adjust color in Swift / iOS 8 - get "Extra Argument Saturation In Call" error

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

I'm learning to use the controls in Swift for iOS. I'm trying to build a simple app that uses the Slider to adjust the background color of the screen using the UIColor class.

```
// function is called when slider is moved.
@IBAction func sliderValueChanged(sender: UISlider) {

    // creates variable to hold new color
    var newBackgroundColor : UIColor

    // creates variable holding the value from slider
    var sliderValue = slider.value

    // changes the newBackgroundColor variable to new color values. 
    newBackgroundColor = UIColor(hue: sliderValue, saturation: 0.5, brightness: 0.5, alpha: 0.5)

    // changes the background color
    self.view.backgroundColor = newBackgroundColor
```

The slider seems to be connected correctly, and the code for adjusting the background works. I've created a variable to hold the value of the slider (between 0.0 and 1.0) but when I try to insert this variable into the UIColor code it comes up with an error "Extra Argument Saturation In Call".

PS: Sorry if the code is scrappy. It's my first post (I can't post images yet).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because `sliderValue` is of type `Float`, but hue is of type `CGFloat`. You can cast it like this.

```
let sliderValue = CGFloat(slider.value)
```

Comment: Thank you very much. That works. Also I spotted the Hue type listed as CGFloat in the Reference File and will look for it in future. Thanks for helping me learn something today.